# Rails Installed But Not Working

Tags: command-line, installation, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ubuntu-12.10

Folks,

Yesterday I installed Rails 3.2 on Ubuntu 12.10 and created a new project in order to check it. It was working OK.

Today I tried to create a new project and got the message bellow (Portuguese version):

O programa 'rails' pode ser encontrado nos seguintes pacotes:

 * rails

 
 * ruby-railties-3.2

 
Tente: sudo apt-get install <pacote selecionado>

Something like:

**The program 'rails' could not be found in the follow packages:**

...

...

**Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>**

I run the command **gem list** and all the gems are listed, including Rails one.

I tried to search on the web for a solution, but haven't found any.

Thank you very much for your help.

Luiz

Comment: Did you install rails as a gem? It sounds like your gems haven't been added to your PATH? When you `echo $PATH` do you see something like /var/lib/gems/... ?

Comment: Yes, Enrico. I installed as a gem. I added the line **source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm** to the bashrc and now it works. Thanks too.

Comment: Good to hear you got it fixed. You should post your own solution and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `/home/(yourUser)/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/bin` to your PATH-Variable

Easiest way to do that is to add that line to your ~/.bashrc and restart your shell:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/(yourUser)/.gem/ruby/1.9.3/bin
```

Remeber to replace `(yourUser)` with your user name and make sure, ruby version is correct ;)

Comment: Hello, Phortx. I added the line, but it didn't work. When I added the line **source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm** to the bashrc, it worked. Thank you very much anyway. Luiz